# register_shutdown_function() not working

Tags: php, apache, function, fastcgi, fpm

I have 2 servers :

- **1) PHP Version 7.0.28-1~dotdeb+8.1**

> System    Linux online 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.51-2
>   (2017-12-03) x86_64 Server API    FPM/FastCGI Virtual Directory
>   Support   disabled Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /etc/php/7.0/fpm

- **2) PHP Version 5.6.34-1~dotdeb+7.1**

> System    Linux ovh 3.14.32-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #6
>   SMP Wed Jan 20 18:22:32 CET 2016 x86_64 Build Date    Mar 12 2018
>   09:28:40 Server API   CGI/FastCGI Virtual Directory Support   disabled
>   Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php5/cgi

On server 1 it works great when i have an error it call HTTP0.html,

```
<?php register_shutdown_function(function(){
$last_error = error_get_last();
if ( !empty($last_error) &&
    $last_error['type'] & (E_ERROR | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR | E_USER_ERROR)
)
{
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ErrorPages/HTTP0.html');
    exit(1);
}
});
echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

But on the server 2 : When i have an error it doesn't change anything :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /var/www....

I think the difference is FPM vs CGI

Thanks for your help

Comment: Anyone have the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution to help everyone : 
I use PHP.ini to prepend a file (prepend.php) with this code

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
define('WEBMASTER_EMAIL', 'xxx@gmail.com');
function error_type($id) {
    switch($id) {
        case E_ERROR:// 1
            return 'E_ERROR';
        case E_WARNING:// 2
            return 'E_WARNING';
        case E_PARSE:// 4
            return 'E_PARSE';
        case E_NOTICE:// 8
            return 'E_NOTICE';
        case E_CORE_ERROR:// 16
            return 'E_CORE_ERROR';
        case E_CORE_WARNING:// 32
            return 'E_CORE_WARNING';
        case E_COMPILE_ERROR:// 64
            return 'E_COMPILE_ERROR';
        case E_COMPILE_WARNING:// 128
            return 'E_COMPILE_WARNING';
        case E_USER_ERROR:// 256
            return 'E_USER_ERROR';
        case E_USER_WARNING:// 512
            return 'E_USER_WARNING';
        case E_USER_NOTICE:// 1024
            return 'E_USER_NOTICE';
        case E_STRICT:// 2048
            return 'E_STRICT';
        case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:// 4096
            return 'E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR';
        case E_DEPRECATED:// 8192
            return 'E_DEPRECATED';
        case E_USER_DEPRECATED:// 16384
            return 'E_USER_DEPRECATED';
    }
    return 'UNKNOWN';
}
function error_alert() {
    // send alert
    if(!is_null($e = error_get_last())) {
        $type = error_type($e["type"]);
        if (strpos($type, 'ERROR') !== false || strpos($type, 'PARSE') !== false) {
            mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, $type . ' in ' . $e['file'] . ' at line ' . $e['line'], $e['message']);
            require_once(__DIR__.'/HTTP0.html');
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
register_shutdown_function('error_alert');
?>
```